# C - Trouble with Pointers to Functions

Tags: c, function-pointers

My partner and I are working on this problem that involves pointers to functions. The goal is write a function that applies a number of string processing functions to a string. The function then returns an array of strings with the results of each of the processing functions on the input string. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

```
char** string_central(char*(**)(char*), char* str);
char* char_double(char* str);
char* char_shift(char* str);
char* char_flip(char* str);

void main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    char* (*functions[])(char *) = {char_double, char_shift, char_flip, NULL};
    char** result = string_central(functions, *argv);
    char* result_ptr = *result;
    while( result_ptr ){
        printf("Result: %s", result_ptr);
        result_ptr++;
    }

}
char** string_central(char*(*functions[])(char*), char* str){
    char** returnArray = (char **) malloc(100*sizeof(char));
    char** firstposition = returnArray;
    while(*functions != NULL) {
        *(returnArray)++ = (*(functions))(str);
    }
    *(returnArray)++ = "\0";
    return firstposition;
}

//Other Functions work properly
```

Comment: Have you run it under a debugger?  Where does it crash?

Comment: `It compiles correctly using GCC, but it doesn't function correctly` Wow. You've discovered a brand new thing. Oh. wait. No. No you haven't. You have discovered a bug in your code! Now you can apply standard debugging techniques like using a debugger to identify and fix the problem.

Comment: In some functional languages there is a function called `juxt` which takes a list of functions, and returns a new function which applies its arguments through each of those functions, and returns a list of those results (i.e.the juxtaposition of the argument(s) projected through each of the functions).

Comment: Have you tried calling your functions directly to see if they work on their own?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use malloc in the string_central like this => (100 * sizeof(char*)). Size of a character is usually 1 byte, size of any pointer is usually 4 bytes. (IIRC)

Oh and, remember to free the memory sometime after they are used.

Answer (score 0):

Most obviously, your `string_central` function calls the first function in the passed functions array repeatedly, in an infinite loop, running off the end of the `returnArray` allocation and corrupting memory.  You need to increment the `functions` pointer in the loop.

You're allocating space for 100 `char`s in the `returnArray`, not 100 pointers, and you never check for overflow (either of this array or any of the allocated strings), so if your input string is too long, you'll overflow.

You mark the end of the `returnArray` with an empty string (rather than a NULL pointer, which might make more sense).

Your `char_XXX` functions do not NUL-terminate the strings they create.

Back in main, when you try to print the result, you only print the first string in `returnArray` and then you increment a pointer along that string, printing parts of that same string, removing initial characters one at a time.

Finally, you never free any of the memory you allocate.